# How do I add People Search in the search drop down?

Tags: user-profile, search-scope

We have a new test box and I like to put people search in the main search drop down. How is it done? I tried googling and it talks about setting up user profile which I already did. and sync is working and I now have population in user profile. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Create a search center in the root site collection.

From the site collection in question, navigate to Site Settings, Search Settings (under Site Collection Administration).  Or navigate to http://yoursitename/_layouts/enhancedSearch.aspx 
Here you want to choose 'Enable custom scopes' and enter your search center address (i.e. /searchcenter/pages).

You can then decide what scopes to show with the Site Collection Search Dropdown mode choice on that same screen.